# EASTRON SDM230-Modbus "Failed to read voltage. Connection timed out."

Tags: connection-timeout

I am using an EASTRON SDM230-Modbus energy meter to read the charasteristics of my solar export.  I have tried a number of "tutorial" code examples.  They all have the same core components -

if (!ModbusRTUClient.requestFrom(01, INPUT_REGISTERS, 1, 2))

followed by -

uint16_t word1 = ModbusRTUClient.read();
uint16_t word2 = ModbusRTUClient.read();

I am using a RAK5005 "motherboard" + RAK5802 Modbus interface

I'm getting no joy at all.  Please see the attached screenshot of the oputput.

Here is the code -  I am using SDM230-Modbus register addressing.

```
// -----------------------------------------
// SDM230-Modbus Energy Meter to Arduino ModbusRTU Client
// -----------------------------------------
 
#include <ArduinoRS485.h>
#include <ArduinoModbus.h>
#include <LoRaWan-RAK4630.h>

constexpr auto baudrate {9600};

// Calculate preDelay and postDelay in microseconds as per Modbus RTU Specification
// MODBUS over serial line specification and implementation guide V1.02
// Paragraph 2.5.1.1 MODBUS Message RTU Framing
// https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf

constexpr auto bitduration { 1.f / baudrate };
constexpr auto preDelayBR { bitduration * 9.6f * 3.5f * 1e6 };
constexpr auto postDelayBR { bitduration * 9.6f * 3.5f * 1e6 };
// constexpr auto preDelayBR { bitduration * 10.0f * 3.5f * 1e6 };

unsigned long rate = 6000;                            
unsigned long lastMillis = 0;
float voltage;
float current;
float power;
float frequency;
float exportEnergy;


void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);                        
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("\nModbus RTU Client\n");
  RS485.setDelays(preDelayBR, postDelayBR);
    
  if (!ModbusRTUClient.begin(baudrate, SERIAL_8N1)) 
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to start Modbus RTU Client!");
        while (1);
    }

}


void loop() 
{ 
  if (millis() - lastMillis > rate)   
   {
    lastMillis = millis();
  
    voltage = readVoltage();
    delay(100);
    current = readCurrent();
    delay(100);
    power = readPower();
    delay(100);
    frequency = readFreq();
    delay(100);
    exportEnergy = readExportEnergy();
  
    Serial.print("\nVoltage = " + String(voltage, 1) + " V   Current = " + String(current, 1) + " A   Power = " + String(power, 1) + " W   Freq = ");
    Serial.println(String(frequency, 1) + " Hz   Export Energy = " + String(exportEnergy, 1) + " kWh\n");
    delay(100);
  }   
}

 
float readVoltage() 
{
  float volt = 0.;
  
  if (!ModbusRTUClient.requestFrom(01, INPUT_REGISTERS, 1, 2))    
  {    
    Serial.print("Failed to read the voltage. ");   
    Serial.println(ModbusRTUClient.lastError()); 
  } 
  else 
  {
    // Response handler 
    Serial.println(ModbusRTUClient.available());
    uint16_t word1 = ModbusRTUClient.read();         
    uint16_t word2 = ModbusRTUClient.read();         
    uint32_t volt = word1 << 16 | word2;             
    return volt;
}



float readCurrent()                                                                             
{        
  float ampere = 0.;
     
  if (!ModbusRTUClient.requestFrom(0x01, INPUT_REGISTERS, 7, 2))                            
  {
    Serial.print("Failed to read the current. ");                                               
    Serial.println(ModbusRTUClient.lastError());         
  } 
  else 
  {        
    // Response handler 
    uint16_t word1 = ModbusRTUClient.read();                                       
    uint16_t word2 = ModbusRTUClient.read();                                         
    int32_t ampere = word1 << 16 | word2;                                              
  }

  return ampere;
}


double readPower()                                                                     
{
  double watt = 0.;
  
  if (!ModbusRTUClient.requestFrom(0x01, INPUT_REGISTERS, 13, 2))                     
  {
      
    Serial.print("Failed to read power. ");                                                    
    Serial.println(ModbusRTUClient.lastError());
  } 
  else 
  {
    // Response handler 
    uint16_t word1 = ModbusRTUClient.read();                                                    
    uint16_t word2 = ModbusRTUClient.read();                                                    
    int32_t watt = word1 << 16 | word2;                                                         
  }

  return watt;
}


float readFreq()                                                                                
{
  float freq = 0.;
  
  if (!ModbusRTUClient.requestFrom(0x01, INPUT_REGISTERS, 71, 2))                           
  {
      
    Serial.print("Failed to read frequency. ");                                                  
    Serial.println(ModbusRTUClient.lastError());
  } 
  else 
  {
    // Response handler 
    uint16_t word1 = ModbusRTUClient.read();                                                     
    uint16_t word2 = ModbusRTUClient.read();                                                    
    int32_t freq = word1 << 16 | word2;                                                          
  }
  return freq;
}


double readExportEnergy()                                                                           
{
  double kwh = 0.;
  
  if (!ModbusRTUClient.requestFrom(0x01, INPUT_REGISTERS, 75, 2))
  { 
    Serial.print("Failed to read energy. ");              
    Serial.println(ModbusRTUClient.lastError());
  } 
  else 
  {
    // Response handler 
    uint16_t word1 = ModbusRTUClient.read();           
    uint16_t word2 = ModbusRTUClient.read();        
    int32_t dwh = word1 << 16 | word2;               
    kwh = dwh/10000.0;                                                           
  }
  return kwh;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Ive checked wiring.  Ive checked the code